# Difference in output of a responsive website

Tags: html, css, responsiveness

I am working on a responsive website which is powerplumb.com.au. For all phone resolutions, I am testing the responsiveness using the tool responsivetest.net. Everything looks perfectly fine for iPhone 5(Screen resolution of 320X568.

However, when I open the same site in Safari on iPhone 5 device, the output is not responsive.

Tried multiple things but it didn't work. What baffles me is that even with same resolution, why the output is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `meta tag` in your `head` section

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" dir="ltr">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/templates/sb_powerplumb/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/templates/sb_powerplumb/favicon.ico" />
   <base href="http://www.powerplumbhydronicheating.com.au/" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="hydronic heating, hydronic heating panel, hydronic heating system, hydronic heating panel installation, hydronic heating melbourne, australia" />
  <meta name="author" content="Super User" />
  <meta name="description" content="PowerPlumb installs Hydronic heating systems, including radiator panels in Melbourne, Australia. " />
  <meta name="generator" content="Joomla! - Open Source Content Management" />
  <title>Power Plumb Hydronic Heating</title>
  <link href="/templates/sb_powerplumb/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/plugins/editors/jckeditor/typography/typography2.php" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/components/com_rsform/assets/themes/green/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/components/com_rsform/assets/css/front.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/components/com_rsform/assets/js/script.js?v=46" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/caption.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/mootools-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('load', function() {
    new JCaption('img.caption');
   });
  </script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/sb_powerplumb/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/templates/sb_powerplumb/js/CreateHTML5Elements.js"></script>
  
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks. Somehow, this was removed by my colleague and I thought it was always in there. Thank you.